# Swagger 1.3.7 and Jersey 2.15/2.16 issue: the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource

Tags: jersey-2.0, swagger

I have a REST API that was working with Jersey 2.6 and Swagger 1.3.7. I read that Jersey 2.9 fixes a warning that I was getting so I upgraded to the latest Jersey 2.16 but then Swagger stopped working. I went back and upgraded one version at a time until I saw that Swagger was working with 2.15 so I settled on that. Now, the PUT API fails with Swagger with the following error:

The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method

The API works using FireFox RESTClient and specifying "application/json".

I do have "jersey-media-json-jackson" as a dependency and call "Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacksonFeature.class);" in the program.

I tried upgrading Swagger but that did not help.

Has Swagger been verified to work with Jersey 2.15/2.16?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently managed to get swagger-core to work with Jersey 2.16 with a similar issue. Keep in mind they are using the latest version (1.5.X) and not 1.3.X but the same solution will apply.

The problem is most likely with version resolution, specifically, the one of jackson-databind. For some reason, even jersey-media-json-jackson 2.16 depends on an older version of jackson-databind, even though it works fine with the latest version. Without having more details, it would be difficult to suggest a full solution, but you can follow the dependency tree and see the conflicts there.

If you do require further assistance, I'd suggest either using our mailing list, or even better, the IRC channel where we could interact online and resolve it.